# How to stretch this Venn diagram?

Tags: plotting, sets

I am trying to duplicate (approximately) the following Venn diagram in Mathematica:

> [image]

I have used the [top of this page](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/improved-visualization-labeling/venn-diagram.html?product=mathematica) as a guide, which showcases the following Venn diagram triplet:

```
a = Disk[{0, 1}];
b = Disk[{-0.5, 0}];
c = Disk[{0.5, 0}];
subsets = Subsets[{a, b, c}, {1, 3}];
subsetscolors = Map[
Function[{c}, 
Blend[
Flatten[
Map[Table[
Map[Append[#, 1.5/Length[c]]& , c], 2]& , c]]]], 
Subsets[
Map[
ColorData[112], 
Range[3]], {1, 4}]];
RegionPlot[Evaluate[DiscretizeRegion[
     RegionDifference[
      BooleanRegion[And, #], 
      BooleanRegion[Or, Complement[{a, b, c, EmptyRegion[2]}, #]]
      ]
     ] & /@ subsets], 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Callout[(StringJoin @@@ Subsets[{"A", "B", "C"}, {1, 3}]), 
   Center], Sequence[
 PlotStyle -> subsetscolors, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[
Thickness[0.01], White], Frame -> False, LabelStyle -> {24}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 450]]
```

> [image]

**Attempted code:**

```
a = Disk[{0, 1}];
b = Disk[{-0.5, 0}];
c = Disk[{0.5, 0}];
subsets = Subsets[{b, c}, {1, 2}];
subsetscolors = 
  Map[Function[{c}, 
    Blend[Flatten[
      Map[Table[Map[Append[#, 1.5/Length[c]] &, c], 2] &, c]]]], 
   Subsets[Map[ColorData[112], Range[2]], {1, 4}]];
RegionPlot[
 Evaluate[DiscretizeRegion[
     RegionDifference[BooleanRegion[And, #], 
      BooleanRegion[Or, Complement[{b, c, EmptyRegion[2]}, #]]]] & /@ 
   subsets], 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Callout[{"Vive", "Linux", "Vive\n\[Intersection]\nLinux"}, Center], 
 Sequence[PlotStyle -> subsetscolors, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], White], Frame -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> {24}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ImageSize -> Automatic]]
```

> [image]

The problem is that it is squashed, and I can't figure out why. How to fix?

Comment: Try setting the `Aspect Ratio->...` option by hand.

Comment: Setting `AspectRatio -> 0.7` somewhat fixes the issue, but the circles are now "jagged". Is there not a way for Mathematica to interpolate this automatically?

Comment: You also have `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` which is going to make the plot fast, and rough. When you've got what you want change that to "Quality" and you should see the edges sharpen up.

Answer (score 11):

I get a decent looking result with:

```
RegionPlot[
 Evaluate[DiscretizeRegion[
     RegionDifference[BooleanRegion[And, #], 
      BooleanRegion[Or, Complement[{b, c, EmptyRegion[2]}, #]]], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}] & /@ subsets], 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Callout[{"Vive", "Linux", "Vive\n\[Intersection]\nLinux"}, Center], 
 Sequence[PlotStyle -> subsetscolors, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], White], Frame -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> {24}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ImageSize -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

which has two changes from your code:

- adds `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}` to the call the `DiscretizeRegion` to have a finer discretization
- uses `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to automatically get the aspect ratio that makes the disks not be stretched

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
Graphics[{
  Opacity[0.5],
  Red, Disk[{-0.66, 0}],
  Blue, Disk[{0.66, 0}],
  Opacity[1], White,
  Text[Style["Vive Users", 18], {-0.8, 0}],
  Text[Style["Linux Users", 18], {0.85, 0}],
  Text[Style["Vive\n⋂\nLinux", 18], {0, 0}]}]
```

[image]